# Preserving active query params when transitioning to a nested route

Tags: ember.js

I have an application that has customer profiles. The route is `/customers/:id`.

I also have a lot of nested routes, like `/customers/:id/notes`, `/customers/:id/tasks` and so on.

On the `customer` route, there is a query param called `source` that's set depending on which route the user transitioned from (and is used to show some context specific data).

That can be achieved like so:

`{{#link-to "customer" customer.id (query-params source="someSource")}}`

However, when I move to a sub route (like the `notes` route):

`{{#link-to "customer.notes" customer.id}}`

... the current active query params go back to default. I know this can be avoided if I pass in the currently active `source` to the `notes` route as well like this:

`{{#link-to "customer.notes" customer.id (query-params source=source)}}`

... but I have a *lot* of nested routes , so I want to know if there is a way to avoid passing in the currently active `source` query param everywhere and instead handle this on a higher level?